# how to dynamically populate facebook dialog content

Tags: facebook, dynamic, share

I have a simple site (not a facebook app) with a flash movie player and playlist.

when a user chooses a video to play, the video's title, desc., and thumbnail are stored in js variables.

now I would like for the user to have a facebook share option, such that when the user shares, the video-specific info is used to populate the facebook share dialog box.

any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Answer (score 0):

when you creating playlist with share button, you create share link with video specific infos.

seems like http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={video url}&t={string video title} and facebook will capture related content.

Comment: Eray, thanks for responding.

as I understand, sharer is now deprecated(??)

I have tried using sharer, though, about 6 months ago for this purpose, and I was unable to get it to handle the dynamic content ...